# How do I convert native pointer to managed handle?

Tags: c++-cli

I am new to c++/cli. In a c++ file with mixed code, I have a native pointer I1*. I1 is a COM interface. I want to convert the native pointer to I1^. Casting throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Marshal::GetObjectForIUnknown()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getobjectforiunknown.aspx).  Cast the return value.

Comment: Hi Hans, `Marshal::GetObjectForIUnknown` expects an `IntPtr`. What is the correct way to call it when only a native pointer is present? `IntPtr((void*)nativePtr)` does not seem to work.

Comment: If nativePtr is a COM interface pointer, use `static_cast<IntPtr>(nativePtr.GetInterfacePtr())`

Answer (score 0):

I expected something like IntPtr instead of the I1^